# Onedrive.login.live and other microsoft.login.live URLs will not connect to the DNS

Tags: windows, dns, onedrive

I managed to access the websites after running disk cleanup and deleting everything but delivery optimization files and also clearing my browser history and cookies on chrome, but I suddenly lost access again.
The main issue is that I don't stay logged in to OneDrive. I constantly have to sign back in and when I try to do so I get an error that I am not connected to the internet..but every other website works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run TCP/IP Reset / DNS Flush:

> 1. Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
> 2. netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
> 3. ipconfig /flushdns
> 4. When all is complete, restart and test.

If after this is done and if you have the same problem, run Windows 10 Initial Repairs (I trust this is Windows 10).

> Still in an Admin Command
>
> dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /startcomponentcleanup
>
> dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth
>
> SFC /SCANNOW
>
> Then restart as before and test.

Let us hope this works for you, because bigger repairs are needed if not.

Comment: I did that once and the problem returned

Comment: I amended my answer to add initial Windows 10 repairs.